# Chaining task pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, task, threadpool

So i'm trying to chain tasks here, but on compiling with GCC under linux, i get the warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]. Even though i'm just working with pointers of the same type.

```
typedef struct
{
    void (*routine)(void*);
    void* data;

    struct p_task* next;
    struct p_task* prev;

    int deadline;
    int timeWaiting;
}p_task;
typedef struct 
{   
    pthread_t mainThread;   

    pthread_t* threadArray;
    int threadCount;

    p_task* firstInLine;
    p_task* lastInLine;
}p_pool;


void pool_add_task(p_pool* pool, void* routine, void* data)
{   
    // create new task
    p_task* task = malloc(sizeof(p_task));
    task->routine = routine;
    task->data = data;
    task->deadline = 5;
    task->timeWaiting = 0;

    // when no tasks are chained yet
    if (pool->firstInLine == NULL) 
    {
        pool->firstInLine = task;
        pool->lastInLine = task;
    }
    else
    {       
        pool->lastInLine->next = task; // bad line 1
        task->prev = pool->lastInLine; // bad line 2
        pool->lastInLine = task; // new task is last in line
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line does the message correspond to?

Comment: I put 2 comments behind the bad lines it's mainly when using the prev or next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `struct p_task` is forward-declared, since you don't use it in the definition of the struct. That means the compiler doesn't know that

1. it does exist at all
2. that it is identical to (`typdef`fed to) the `p_task` type.

You need to write this:

```
typedef struct p_task
{
    // etc.
} p_task;
```